# Get-Childitem cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'X' does not exist

Tags: powershell, mapped-drive

I'm writing a script to copy files with powershell using mapped drives in file explorer.  It has the above error message.  This is what it looks like:

```
function CopyFileToFolderUNC($SourcePath, $DestinationPath){
   $temp1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Recurse -Force #this is the line of error message
   Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath -Destination $DestinationPath #source:\* -Destination target  #watch out for login boxes when test this
}

#start here
$tempSource = "X:\Credentialing\FORMS"
$ToLocation = "C:\Users\me\Documents\2018\powershellFiles\toLoc" 

CopyFileToFolderUNC $tempSource $ToLocation
```

It has the same error message on the Copy-Item line (if I comment out the Get-ChildItem line) but it fails in Get-ChildItem before that.  **How do I get it to use the mapped drive on the computer the script is run on?** I am running this on a laptop.

I set-executionPolicy RemoteSigned in powershell at the command line.

I have this permission when I run Get-PSSessionConfiguration in powershell at command line:

> Permission    : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed,
>   BUILTIN\Administrators AccessAllowed, BUILTIN\Remote Management Users
>   AccessAllowed

I am running as administrator. Powershell prompt is:

> [DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>>

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  -------- 
5      1      16299  666
```

I looked at [powershell mapped drive E](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e81ab439-dcae-4904-a8ef-56f52fa4c8ed/cannot-find-drive-a-drive-with-the-name-e-does-not-exist?forum=winserverpowershell) but they are using a mapped drive on a server so I wasn't sure what I needed that they were doing in the example.

Comment: This [Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to "Prompt for credentials" in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co) may very well be the cause. If you name your function `CopyFileToFolderUNC` then why give the source as a local path instead of a UNC path??

Answer (score 1):

I found this: [Net use](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0d462497-ec04-4428-b5af-d7334cacad3d/powershell-and-only-powershell-cant-see-network-drives?forum=winserverpowershell)

So I added

```
if(-Not (Test-Path "X:\")) {net use X: \\NDRIVE01\Svcs_FG}
```

And now it's at least finding the mapped drive.

Comment: but my question remains: why not go for the UNC path in the first place???